# Can I benefit from Redux's core principles in a React app without installing Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

From the [redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles), "Redux can be described in three fundamental principles: Single source of truth, State is read-only, Changes are made with pure functions."

As someone relatively new to React, and in the process of assessing the need to learn Redux, I am confused because these principles seem to either already exist in React, or be implementable in React by simply adopting conventions.  Is Redux mostly about writing code a certain way, or does it do something I don't understand yet?

### Single source of truth

How is this different from the React concept of managing state in the component that is the highest common owner (or higher)?  Would you achieve a "single source of truth" if you designate a single component in your whole app for managing state?  Would that produce pitfalls that are somehow avoided when I install Redux?

### State is read-only

React state is already immutable, so it sounds like this principle is already fully captured by React.  I see the Redux documentation mentions "subtle race conditions" but I don't see that mentioned in the React documentation.  When would such race conditions become a problem?  Could I avoid them without Redux?

### Changes are made with pure functions

Redux is very specific about *how* they alter state: using pure function reducers with a single, flexible function prototype.  The benefits are stated as "you can control the order in which they are called, pass additional data, or even make reusable reducers..." I'm admittedly unclear on how call-order would get controlled in just React, but it seems like the other benefits (passing additional data, and reusable reducers) would come from just adopting the conventions:

```
changeState( state, action )
```

where action looks like:

```
{type: "action identifier", data: <data needed to complete action> }
```

and changeState() contains a switch based on action.type, doesn't produce side-effect, and depends only on the passed parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The `ContextApi` and `Hooks` are what you need. There is actions, reducers, and context is immutable.

Note that Redux exists because React `ContextApi` was unstable until react 16.8 (If i remember well). Now that it is fully operational, go for it. Hooks will give you the tools you need to handle it easily.

I always refer to [this article](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c) to setup my context because it is the easiest way to handle it I think, but you should read the documentation before.

Comment: The only thing that seems wrong about this article is the fact that it "recommends" side effects / middleware in reducer. You should always handle side effects with useEffect and keep the reducers pure. I would suggest this article: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react

Comment: @ArberSylejmani I see that statement for middleware but yes you're right, side effect like http call have to be managed by useEffect. However, I don't know where you can manage your middleware else than in the 'mainReducer'. this 'mainReducer' isn't the reducer so it does not impact the purity of the returned reducer. But I'm not familiar with middleware so..

Comment: You don't add middleware, in the reducer. You have useEffect(() => { console.log('second'); return () => console.log('first') }, []). This is the order of how functions are called in useEffect, meaning you can use useEffect either before the state update or after. Usually the one that logs 'first' is called the cleanup but it happens before a state update, and the 'second' after the state is updated. So you can do whatever here.

Comment: The `ContextApi ` might not be as performant as `Redux`. The `connect` API in redux ensures that only components that reference a specific part of the store based on your reducers get re-rendered on data changes.
However, do not micro optimize prematurely. In many cases your application is going to perform well without Redux. And there are ways to optimize the performance in other ways like the `useMemo` hook.

Comment: @DmitryS.you're probably right but it's not part of the subject here. I don't think there is something else that could replace redux, except other flux-based libraries